# Ruby Rspec returning nil after validation in the method

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying to use below `place method` to return `true` instead of `nil` from Rspec Unit testing:

**Class**

```
require 'active_model'
require_relative 'board'
require_relative 'direction'
require_relative 'report'

class Actions
    include ActiveModel::Validations

    attr_accessor :board

    def initialize
        @board = Board.new
        @move = Direction::Move.new
        @report = Report.new
    end

    def place(x_coordinate, y_coordinate, direction = :north)
        x_coordinate.between?(@board.left_limit, @board.right_limit) && 
        y_coordinate.between?(@board.bottom_limit, @board.top_limit) &&
        @move.directions.grep(direction).present?

        @report.log(x_coordinate, y_coordinate, direction)  
    end

end
```

**Rspec test**

```
require_relative '../spec_helper'
require 'board'
require 'actions'
require 'direction'

describe Board do

    let(:board) { Board.new }
    let(:action) { Actions.new }

    describe '#initialize' do
        it { expect(board.valid?).to be_true }
        it { expect(action.valid?).to be_true }
    end

    describe 'validations' do
        it 'should not exceed top limit' do
            expect(action.place(1, 6)).to be_false
        end 

        it 'should not exceed bottom limit' do
            expect(action.place(1, 0)).to be_false
        end

        it 'should not exceed right limit' do
            expect(action.place(6, 1)).to be_false
        end

        it 'should not exceed left limit' do
            expect(action.place(0, 1)).to be_false
        end

        it 'should place robot within its limits' do
            expect(action.place(1, 1)).to be_true
        end

        it 'should not accept non-integer values' do
            expect{action.place('a', 'b')}.to raise_error(ArgumentError)
        end
    end

    describe 'actions' do
        it 'place the robot on the board facing south' do
            expect(action.place(1, 1, Direction::South)).to be_true
        end
    end

end
```

All tests that should be returning true value are failing and getting nil returned

Is there a way to return true if validations are passed?

Comment: Your method will be returning whatever Report's `log` method returns.

Comment: I want to run report.log only when above validations are true and then return true on report.log is there a way to do this in the current place method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `place` will return whatever you make it return, either with an explicit `return`, or from the last statement evaluated in the method. Currently the return value is whatever `@report.log(x_coordinate, y_coordinate, direction)` returns. Which is probably always `nil` (which in turn happens to match `be_false`, but not match `be_true`). There is nothing I can see wrong with the spec.

The test failures are real, the code under test has a bug. Probably you should just put the log message as the first statement in the `place` method, like this:

```
def place(x_coordinate, y_coordinate, direction = :north)
    @report.log(x_coordinate, y_coordinate, direction)  

    x_coordinate.between?(@board.left_limit, @board.right_limit) && 
    y_coordinate.between?(@board.bottom_limit, @board.top_limit) &&
    @move.directions.grep(direction).present?
end
```